# Unable to use "this" in makeStyle

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I would like to create a dynamic background image depending on my props. So for that I wanted to make a react style and give it the picture stored in my `state` but I can't use `this.state.pictures` in it and I don't know why.

```js
class DisplayArtist extends Component {
    
    state = {
        name : this.props.Info.artists.items[0].name,
        followers: this.props.Info.artists.items[0].followers.total,
        genres: this.props.Info.artists.items[0].genres,
        picture: this.props.Info.artists.items[0].images[0]
    }

    useStyles = makeStyles({
        root: {
            backgroundImage={this.state.pictures}
        }
    });
```

Comment: React hooks are incompatible with class-based components. `makeStyles` returns a `useStyles` react hook. You can try using the [withStyles](https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/#higher-order-component-api) HOC, but I don't this will quite work for you since the HOC wraps your component and won't have access to state.

Comment: @DrewReese If I make an arrow function instead of a class, would it be fine ?

Comment: Sure, convert the component to a functional component and you can use `makeStyles` and resultant `useStyles` hook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. makeStyles is better used in a functional component, rather than a class component.
2. using makeStyes inside a function component causes the style to be recreated on every render. I don't recommend doing it that way.

The recommended approach is to use inline styles for dynamic background images

```
e.g. style={{ backgroundImage: artist.images[0] }}
```

**Converting to Functional Component**

```
const DisplayArtist = (props) => {

    const [ artist, setArtist ] = useState(null);
    
    useEffect(() => {

       //do your own checks on the props here.
       const { name, total, genres, images } = props.Info.artists.items[0]
       setArtist({name, total, genres, images});

    },[props])

    return ( <div style={{ width: '200px', height:'200px', backgroundImage: artist.images[0] }} /> )
}

export default DisplayArtist
```

Comment: I converted my class to arrow function, but when I try to use the `backgroundImage` in the style, nothing displayed on my screen.

Comment: Debug by isolating the problems. When you right click and inspect the element, did the inline css show up in the inspector? Does it have a height and a width? What else you have in your div? From the question, you did not show any render codes.

Comment: Oh it works by stocking the `picture` into a variable and then using this var in the background image

Comment: I don't understand what's in your codes, whether it's variable or you saving it in a state, I hope you achieved what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Functional Component and use useStyles and pass the state you want to it

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(() => ({
  root: {
    backgroundImage:({ picture }) => ( picture )
  }
}))

function DisplayArtist({Info}) {
  const [picture, setPicture] = useState()

  const classes = useStyles({picture})

}
```

Comment: I just tried this, but it didn't display anything. 
The picture url is this `https://i.scdn.co/image/07d3212da0fccc779c69272060a8b57494b8c3fd` but nothing in my div

Comment: Did you set the initial state for picture.you have to set it using setState in an useEffect

Answer (score -1):

Use Higher-order component API [Higher-Order-Component-Api](https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/#higher-order-component-api)

```
const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
            backgroundImage={this.state.pictures}
        }
});

class DisplayArtist extends Component {
    
    state = {
        name : this.props.Info.artists.items[0].name,
        followers: this.props.Info.artists.items[0].followers.total,
        genres: this.props.Info.artists.items[0].genres,
        picture: this.props.Info.artists.items[0].images[0]
    }

}

export default withStyles(styles)(DisplayArtist);
```

Comment: It doesn't work, still got the problem with the `this.` in the style.

Comment: `this` will still be undefined as it won't be the `this` of the wrapped/decorated component. See [adapting the higher order component api](https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/#adapting-the-higher-order-component-api)... the `styles` object will have access to passed props via a callback syntax.